# Vue.js + Bootstrap-Select: how to avoid render loop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-select

I'm trying to get Vue.js to play nice with [Bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/), but am completely stumped on how to avoid the render loop between the value being set with `.selectpicker('val')`, and being constantly updated by Vue.

Example here:

https://codepen.io/schmoove/pen/EeeVab

`vm.$emit('input', this.value)` (line 10)

Works, but not with multiple selections. However, if you switch to:

`vm.$emit('input', $(this.$el).selectpicker('val'));` (replace line 10 with line 9)

It sends the script into an infinite loop.

I'm relatively new to Vue.js and just can't understand how this should work, or if Bootstrap-select is making things particularly difficult. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Change

`vm.$emit('input', this.value)`

to

`vm.$emit('input', vm.value)`

Comment: That doesn't help unfortunately. You'll see if you select multiple options, the output doesn't update (and it should say Array in the brackets for it to work correctly).

The problem remains that if you uncomment line 9 (comment line 10) - there is still a render loop.

Comment: I have updated the pen to show what I mean. As soon as you change a value, it goes into a render loop and hangs the browser.